# 74HC221 negative edge trigging

Tags: integrated-circuit, proteus

How to use 74HC221 for output variable pulse width on negative edge.

[image]

I tried connect B and MR pins to HIGH and A pin to input as tells in datasheet. But it give huge pulse like 1 second.

[image]

Probably I must use RX and CX pins but don't know how to use and datasheet doesn't tell.

The pulse that i want, must be between 0-10 ms.

I add R4, R5 and C3 change the values of R4 and C3 multiple times but it didn't change the output.

[image]

Then realized this:
"Pin 'CX' is not modelled.
Pin 'RX/CX' is not modelled."
in simulation log. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you could add a bit more context to improve your question. What have you tried? What didn’t work? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Add a resistor from the base of Q1 to GND for a more lean and snappy turn-off,  Also, the regulator needs a capacitor directly at its input, per the datasheet.

Comment: The chart in the lower image has no useful information, just large color blobs.  What are you trying to show?

Comment: @AnalogKid The blue is output from Q. Yellow is Transformer and red transistor their period is 20ms so the problem and want to show the blue is 1s

Comment: @akiftokel - Also be aware of the limits of RX, as shown on page 1:  "The minimum value of external resistance, RX, is typically 500Ω.  The minimum value of external capacitance, CX, is 0pF. The calculation for the pulse width is tW = 0.7 RXCX at VCC = 4.5V."

Comment: @akiftokel - Are you only designing this through a circuit simulator?  If the simulator does not fully model the 74HC221's functionality you may need to make an entry to a model parameter that defines the timing.  If that is the case the attached R and C components may have no effect at all on the circuit simulation.

Comment: @Nedd Yes i want to make test on simulator before real life project. But i agree with you probably they didn't code this component full functional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find an alternative solution because RX and RX/CX pins aren't functional i think.

1. So in edit properties window for component there is "Monostable Time Constant" value. Default value is 1 second so the output was always 1 second. But you can change it whatever you want.
2. And there is hidden pins for VCC and GND so You must add VCC and GND terminal in your circuit.
3. Also B and MR pins must be HIGH and A input for falling edge trigger.

This is result. You can see i add VCC terminal and set monostable time constant value to 5ms so BLUE line in graph shows that.
[image]

Comment: Much better.  If you want to try an actual RC timing circuit see if your simulator has a complete model for a 555 chip. That can also be wired for a mono-stable function.

Answer (score 0):

The [TI 74HC221 data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd54hc221.pdf) clearly shows (on page 2) where the RX,CX components are connected.
For proper operation follow the truth table (same page), be sure you satisfy all input pins.

Input \$B\$ operates with a rising edge, while \$\overline{A}\$ operates with a falling edge. ( Input \$\overline{R}\$ must be held high).

Below is the page 2 that I see.  If this is not what you see your PDF reader App may be outdated.

.[image]
................................................[From: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd54hc221.pdf]

Answer (score 0):

The equation for calculating the values is on page 1 of the datasheet.  Also, figure 8 shows the relationships among R, C, and time.

For your desired time period, you can pick approximate R and C values from the chart, and then fine-tune them for commercially available values with the equation.